# Tab bar item different actions based on current view controller

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, avfoundation

I'm working on a small, tabbar-based photo app in Swift. I'd like the center button to bring up the camera view controller if it's not the currently displayed VC, and act as a "shutter" for taking photos in the camera VC.

While it's obvious to me that it involves a custom action for the tab bar item, I'm puzzled as to which values to use to accomplish it? E.g. what to observe to detect VC currently displayed?

Comment: Can you share any design?

Comment: There are no designs as of yet, just a mockup storyboard of a tab bar controller containing 5 VCs. Didn't really consider it being worth sharing, the question is not directly related to the design anyway.